# How to disable Atomikos logfile when running Spring Boot with Atomikos JTA

Tags: spring-boot, atomikos

I am using Spring Boot with Atomikos with embeded undertow server.I will be running my application in docker as a executable jar.We are writing all our logs as Sysout basically we are flushing and not writing any log files.But Atomikos is creating 3 log files when start and run application under my working directory.

How to disable creation of this log files. We should not create any physical log files in Disk.

or

Is there any way I can make these logs will be written in console instead of creating physical file.

Tried below configuration but it's not working.

com:
  atomikos:
      icatch:
         enable_logging=false

Answer (score 0):

You should run with `-Dcom.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=false` as Atomikos itself does not read your `application.yml` so it will not read properties from there. Spring doesn't set this property either. A bit warning though, right from Atomikos documentation:

> Specifies if disk logging should be enabled or not. Defaults to true.
>   It is useful for JUnit testing, or to profile code without seeing the
>   transaction manager's activity as a hot spot but **this should never be
>   disabled on production or data integrity cannot be guaranteed**.

Transaction logs are as important as data as they're used to recover from failures.

Comment: is there a way I can write these logs in console by any configuration.

Comment: You don't understand. These transaction logs are used to recover from failures and maintain data integrity by the Atomikos Transaction Manager. It has to be able to read these from somewhere automatically. This is not a debug log.

Comment: which means we cannot disable this logs when using Atomikos?Btw -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=false is not disabling creation of log files. As you said this might be used for only disabling INFO kind of logs.